# Only Run or Display a query if its contains data

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010, ms-access-2007, ms-access-2013, ms-access-2016

I have a form to input one field of data. After the data has been input then a query will run. Based of the entry. Is it possible to make it so the query does not open if the the query contains no data, if the query does contain data it must display a message box

Comment: Options: 1. code behind form to determine if filtered query will return records - a DCount() could accomplish; or 2. open a report based on that query and code behind report would cancel report if it has no data. Attempt code and when you have specific issue post question.

Answer (score 1):

You can use *DCount*:

```vb
If DCount("*", "NameOfYourQuery") = 0 Then
    ' No records, do nothing.
Else
    ' At least one record exists.
    MsgBox "Some message"
    DoCmd.OpenQuery "NameOfYourQuery"
End If
```